# python opencv エラー　画像処理　index

Tags: python, opencv

```
import cv2

file="face_01.jpg"
img=cv2.imread(file)
imgray=cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
h,w=imgray.shape
print(imgray[60][39])
```

これを実行すると`IndexError: index 60 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 40`とエラーが出ます。imgrayの座標[60][39]が白か黒かを調べたいのでこのような実行をしました。ちなみにh=40,w=67です。解決策を教えてほしいです。

Answer (score 4):

OpenCVでは、配列(ndarray)の添字の順番は(x,y(,c))ではなく、(y,x(,c))になっています。
これは恐らく、メモリの連続性を考えた時に、普通画像はx方向にメモリを連続に確保するためにyが先になっています。
ご質問のコードは添字のxとyが逆になっているために、画像の範囲外へのアクセスになり、エラーになっているので、添字の順番を変えて、

```
print(imgray[39][60])
```

とすればいいかと。

参考文献:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098104/python-opencv2-cv2-wrapper-get-image-size
numpyはC言語と同じ順番でメモリにデータが格納されているので、array[i,j]とした時には添字jについてメモリは連続になります（Fortranとかだと逆なので注意）
http://kaisk.hatenadiary.com/entry/2015/02/19/224531

Answer (score 0):

[Accessing and Modifying pixel values](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_core/py_basic_ops/py_basic_ops.html#accessing-and-modifying-pixel-values)によると、
以下でpixel値を取得できるようです。

```
px = img[100,100]
```

環境がないため確認できませんが、
以下で解決するかもしれません。

```
import cv2

file="face_01.jpg"
img=cv2.imread(file)
imgray=cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
h,w=imgray.shape
print(imgray[39,60])
```